# Should tag descriptions start with "Questions about" or "To be used"?

Tags: discussion, tags

A lot of the current tags start with "`Questions about...`" (see [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no)), but also do many start with "`To be used...`" (see [close-friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-friends)). I personally prefer the "Questions about" starter, however given their presence I feel many others prefer the use of "to be used", to have consistency I'd like to see which on the community prefers, and then make that one the standard for all tags.

Comment: It depends. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags to get a clear idea. The tags are revised many times by good developers and possess a high standard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter because the site will cut off the beginning of sentences like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the tag page will intentionally exclude some of this introductory text as discussed on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts), I don't know that it really matters. The reasoning in the answer there even emphasizes the fact that the repetitive text takes up spaces unnecessarily and obscures actually valuable content - the part of the excerpt that actually explains how to use the tag.

You can see this in action on the [tag page](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags) by looking at the [work-environment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) tag.  The full excerpt reads:

> Use this tag if the question is related to the work environment, such as an issue with your boss, your coworkers, or someone you have authority over.

But on the tag page it reads only:

> if the question is related to the work environment, such as an issue with your boss, your coworkers, or someone you have authority over.

Or, less usefully, the [awkward-situations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awkward-situations) tag, which reads in full:

> For questions about situations which are awkward for anyone concerned. Should be used when the awkwardness is the key part of the problem.

But on the tag page reads only:

> awkward for anyone concerned. Should be used when the awkwardness is the key part of the problem.

I don't think we need to be pedantic about writing them all the same but we **should** be conscientious about how they get shortened. That being said, we should be happy at this point if the tags have descriptions at all. Once we start requiring a standard, we end up pushing people to potentially mangle their tag description when there may be other ways to word things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it matters. The purpose of the tag wiki is to guide people as to it's usage, as opposed to a definition of the tag. Wiki editors have varying styles of writing tag wikis. If a person feels it can be improved, then the best thing is to write an edit suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

*Expediency might work, like in a dictionary.*

A dictionary will usually not start a definition by saying "This word means A, B, C ..." It will begin simply with "A, B, C ..." (or nearly so).

Using a tag and definition that is just for illustration only, the wiki for `nearly-family` could start as "People who can tell each other anything". I would favor this in lieu of, for instance, "For questions regarding people who can tell each other anything".